Quantised electromagnetic field in quantum optics for an infinite quantiation volume
The electromagnetic field can be quantised by considering the allowed modes in a cube based on the periodic boundary conditions and then quantising those modes. Doing so, we find that the hamiltonian of our system is given by a sum over the Harmonic oscillator energies for each mode (as seen, for example, here) I want to consider the scenario where we extend the quantisation volume to infinite, such that every wave vector is allowed, so that rather than the sum
$$\hat{H}_{EM}=\sum_{\textbf{k},s}\hbar\omega_{ k}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\textbf{k},s}\hat{a}_{\textbf{k},s}$$
we have some integral
$$\hat{H}_{EM}\sim\int d^{3}\textbf{k}\hbar\omega_{ k}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\textbf{k},s}\hat{a}_{\textbf{k},s}$$
Can anyone recommend any resource where this kind of thing is covered?

Any QFT book or lecture would cover such a limit. (And your integral measure is not Lorentz-invariant)

I dont see why you would be stuck here; you are being told to use what is called a box normalisation under Born-von-Karmon PBC, and if you want it to be continuous, you can just take the cube and make its side length infinite. You would have to be careful with some stuff, but it is relatively straightforward.

The sum is almost always fine - just carry $V$ in calculations and in the end, either observe it to cancel out or take the limit $V\to \infty$. Integration over infinite continuous space of $\mathbf k$ would require redefinition of $\hat{a}$'s and for useful cases, such as equilibrium radiation, they would become infinite, because contribution due to $d^3\mathbf k$ has to be infinite in infinite space. Sticking with finite $V$ makes all quantities well behaved.

I believe the quantum optics textbook of Milburn and Walls has this, as well at the Quantum Mechanics textbook of Abers.
